# How to get the audio channel layout string from CMAudioFormatDescription?

Tags: avfoundation, core-audio

I need to get the channel layout for an audio track in a QT movie. I've got as far as reading the CMAudioFormatDescription

```
    "<CMAudioFormatDescription 0x60800011fad0 [0x7fff77314f00]> {
mediaType:'soun'
mediaSubType:'lpcm' 
mediaSpecific: {
ASBD: {mSampleRate: 48000.000000 
mFormatID: 'lpcm' 
mFormatFlags: 0xc 
mBytesPerPacket: 6 
mFramesPerPacket: 1 
mBytesPerFrame: 6 
mChannelsPerFrame: 2 
mBitsPerChannel: 24 } 
cookie: {(null)} 
ACL: {Stereo (L R)} 
} 
extensions: {<CFBasicHash 0x608000668080 [0x7fff77314f00]>{type = immutable dict, count = 1,\nentries =>\n\t1 : <CFString 0x7fff760e2340 [0x7fff77314f00]>{contents = \"VerbatimSampleDescription\"} = <CFData 0x608000365940 [0x7fff77314f00]>{length = 114, capacity = 114, bytes = 0x00000072696e32340000000000000001 ... 0000000000000000}\n}\n}\n}"
```

but I can't work out how to extract the "Stereo (L R)" string from this. I see there is a CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetChannelLayout and that contains a AudioChannelLayoutTag  which in this case is kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo, but where does the "Stereo (L R)" string come from?

Unfortunately I can't get this to work for some reason:

```
size_t layoutSize = 0;
const AudioChannelLayout *layout = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetChannelLayout(audioTrackRef, &layoutSize);

NSString *layoutName = nil;
UInt32 layoutNameSize = sizeof(layoutName);
OSStatus err = AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelLayoutSimpleName, sizeof(layout), &layout, &layoutNameSize, &layoutName);
```

and `layoutName` remains nil, even though I can see "Stereo (L R)" when I print `audioTrackRef`

Comment: What about `kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelLayoutName`?

Comment: I tried that first and got the same nil result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the properties `kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelLayoutName` and `kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelLayoutSimpleName` with `AudioFormatGetProperty` to get what you're after:

```
CFStringRef layoutName = nullptr;
UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(layoutName);
OSStatus result = AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelLayoutName, /* size of your channel layout */, /* your channel layout */, &propertySize, &layoutName);

// later
CFRelease(layoutName);
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't get this to work. The layoutName remains nil. Have edited question.

Comment: Solved it. Was a silly mistake. The AudioChannelLayout is already a pointer but I was passing it as &layout.